# Azure Automation - Run scripts using Azure commands or PowerShell commands

Tags: azure, powershell

I am looking to port production jobs into Azure automation. The goal would be to schedule maintenance from scripts held in a shared drive on all computers in that domain. Using Azure, I could use the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand cmdlet to accomplish this task. Powershell also natively supports running scripts remotely with the Invoke-Command cmdlet.

Is there any particular benefit in using one cmdlet as opposed to another? Invoke-Command assumes you have open communication with the target host, but that is a given in my case. Are there any other drawbacks to using Invoke-Command? What about Invoke-AzVMRunCommand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Azure portal if we want to run any powershell script inside an Azure VM, we use this `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` cmdlet, there it will open the Powershell window to connect to the Azure VM from backend.

The Run Command option is recommended if you need to run scripts inside an Azure VM using the guest agent.

You can also run this command directly from Azure PowerShell, CLI and Cloud Shell as well.

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName '<myResourceGroup>' -Name '<myVMName>' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '<pathToScript>' -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}
```

[image]

For `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand cmdlet` we need to pass the script in the `-ScriptPath` parameter, so the script file has to be in place from where cmdlet is being run. Wherever you are running the script you will need to have the script available there.

**Limitation**:

To Run this command the below permission is needed `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommand/action` .
The Virtual Machine Contributor role and higher levels will have this.

Whereas,
`Invoke-command`  cmdlet is just used to invoke any RestAPI or an action using the PowerShell.

Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2) to know about the Invoke command.